# change des java to triple des

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, 3des

Hi i hav such code that encrypt and decrypt file in DES algorithm . 
i want to change my code to be triple DES encryption / decryption . 
my code is below :

First, my methods are :

public class DESEncrypt 
{

```
public static void encrypt(String key, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Exception {
    encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, is, os);
}

public static void decrypt(String key, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Exception {
    encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, is, os);
}

public static void encryptOrDecrypt(String key, int mode, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Exception {

    DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey desKey = skf.generateSecret(dks);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES"); 

    if (mode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(is, cipher);
        makeFile(cis, os);
    } else if (mode == Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);
        makeFile(is, cos);
    }
}

public static void makeFile(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
    int numBytes;
    while ((numBytes = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        os.write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
}
```

}

public class EncryptTXT extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
String key="Java@123##";    //This is the Key for Encryption




private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{   
    JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser();  
    fc.showOpenDialog(null); 
    String path=fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath(); 
    jLabel2.setText(path);
    File f=fc.getSelectedFile();
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/user/Desktop/encrypted.txt");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    DESEncrypt.encrypt(key, fis, fos);

    jLabel4.setText("C:/Users/user/Desktop/encrypted.txt");
```

Comment: Why? Replacing DES is already a breaking change, so if you do that, switch to something modern like AES-GCM.

Comment: We're not here to do your work. What have you tried?

Comment: Maarten i have tried to replace DES with DESede, but it doesnt work .

Comment: Did you try to generate `"DESede"` keys of 24 bytes? Note that keys are binary, not `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

1. The 3DES keys should be 16 or 24 bytes long, not 8.
2. Change `"DES"` to `"DESede"` as Maarten Bodewes suggested or `"DESede\ECB\NoPadding"` (in `.getInstance()` method)